# Скрытие пользовательского скрипта от редакторов таблицы

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

В таблице есть пользовательские скрипты.

Можно ли от редакторов таблицы скрыть скрипты?

Скрипты они могут запускать, например через меню, но не редактировать, а лучше вообще не видеть. Публиковать скрипт как дополнение пока мне не подходит.

Answer (score 3):

Скрипт, включённый в таблицу, невозможно скрыть от пользователей с правом редакторования таблицы. Право редакторования такого скрипта наследуется от таблицы, согласно [документации](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/collaborating#sharing-a-project):

> if you have a Spreadsheet-bound script, you would make someone an editor of the script by making them an editor of the Spreadsheet.

Если публикация в виде дополнения не подходит, могу предложить как (окольный) вариант публикацию в виде [веб-приложения](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). То есть, разместить основной код в отдельном скрипте с функцией `doGet(e)`. Дать этому скрипту право редактирования таблиц. Опубликовать как приложение в свободном доступе, исполняемое от Вашего аккаунта. Да, над безопасностью здесь нужно задуматься, но если скрипт делает что-то определённое (т.е., изменяет только один документ, указанный в самом скрипте), то это разумно.

Тогда скрипт в составе таблицы будет простым: он только вызывает другой скрипт через [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), с нужными параметрами (продуманными с точки зрения безопасности, т.е.,  никакой набор входных параметров не должен вредить). Редакторы увидят этот скрипт (и смогут его изменить), но доступа к основному коду у них не будет.

Comment: А вариант через библиотеку будет работать? Если код, который хочу скрыть, поместить в библиотеку? А в таблице, которую буду отдавать редакторам, скрипты будут ссылаться на библиотечные функции?

Comment: Так сойдёт, хотя библиотеки отходят в прошлое. Я с этим не работал, поэтому только сошлюсь на   http://stackoverflow.com/q/16075446 (см. также комментарий от Mogsdad).

Comment: Да, через библиотеку код полностью скрыть не получилось. Если редактор таблицы запускает режим отладки,  библиотечный модуль отображается для просмотра.

Comment: @LiveForever, извините, что в отдельном комментарии, но по-другому никак не связаться. Я всегда отмечаю спам тревогой и голосую против, но с недавнего времени стал удалять и содержимое тоже

Comment: @VenZell И напрасно, на мой взгляд. Если спам, то лучше, чтобы он был на виду во всей красе - так он быстрее получает нужные ему 6 тревог.